# Hide wordpress in site url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site (grosvenorauctions.com) uses a modified Wordpress install to create a custom look - the blog part is driven by WP but other parts are outside WP. Consequently the index page for my site is not in the root folder but actually within the Wordpress folder. I am using htaccess (RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.grosvenorauctions.com/wordpress/) to point to the index page in Wordpress but additionally I would like to hide the /wordpress/ part of the url. Is this possible? To be clear the htaccess file I have modified is in the root, not WP's own htaccess file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [L]
```